# ExternalConsentConnectivityProblem Windows Live OAuth

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, windows-live

I am trying to get the list of contacts from hotmail.com. I have registered my application and I was trying to use the sample code provided [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/messengerconnect/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4595) (OAuth Wrap CallBack).

But I am getting the following repose from the server:

```
error_code=1017&wrap_error_reason=ExternalConsentConnectivityProblem
```

I am not sure what the problem is. I entered the right user name and password for providing the consent. Can someone help me fix this issue?

My application can be found [here](http://ftr.phpfogapp.com/test2/index.php).

Thank  You.

Comment: Did you maybe change the scopes in `init.php`?

Comment: Yes, I have scope set to -- define('WRAP_SCOPE', 'WL_Contacts.View');

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like you're using the 4.1 version of Messenger Connect, which is deprecated and no longer working (please see the announcement at the top of this forum).
>   There is some documentation re: moving from OAuth WRAP to OAuth 2.0 here:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx#moving

I have read this answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/4c526036-7874-4615-915c-66e7b77e67dc) (I think you are the asker), I share this to all because I have the same problem and I am going to migrate too.

Comment: You should not use answers to post comments